# Add a Web User Control to a Class Library Project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Can someone tell me how to make it so I have the ability to add WebUserControls (.asxc) to a Class Library project in Visual Studio 2013? I have search everywhere but only found how to do it in old versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the Web Forms User Control item template doesn't get listed if the project is a Class Library.  As a result, the easiest option may be to add a Web Forms project to your solution, add the User Control to it and then drag it into the Class Library project.  You'd need to add the appropriate references to the Class Library project manually.